# React Native apply array values from state as Picker items

Tags: react-native

I have an array in my `state` named `Categories`.

These are its values: `['Food', 'Home', 'Savings']`.

My goal is that I need them to be rendered as `Picker.items` for my user to select.

How is that possible?

I tried using `ListView` inside a `Picker` object, but when I navigate to that page,

> AppName stopped Working

prompts.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You don't need to use listview within [picker](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker.html)

```
var options ={
    "1": "Home",
    "2": "Food",
    "3": "Car",
    "4": "Bank",
};

<Picker
    style={{your_style}}
    mode="dropdown"
    selectedValue={this.state.selected}
    onValueChange={()=>{}}>
    {Object.keys(options).map((key) => {
        return (<Picker.Item label={this.props.options[key]} value={key} key={key}/>) //if you have a bunch of keys value pair
    })}
</Picker>
```

2) When you have an array of values

```
var options =["Home","Savings","Car","GirlFriend"];

<Picker
    style={{your_style}}
    mode="dropdown"
    selectedValue={this.state.selected}
    onValueChange={()=>{}}> //add your function to handle picker state change
    {options.map((item, index) => {
        return (<Picker.Item label={item} value={index} key={index}/>) 
    })}
</Picker>
```

Comment: Hello Sir, Thank You for the solution, It worked, but it alerted warnings. It says 'React.createElement: type is invalid' 
Sir where FROM will I import the Item component?

Comment: Never mind, I just changed the <Item/> to <Picker.Item />. The alerts were gone after that. Thank you again Kind Sir.

Comment: Hi bro, I am not 'SIR' just a fellow programmer like you.You can replace Item with Picker.Item or check https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker.html for example

Comment: @ManjeetSingh when tried like `{options.map((item, index) => {
        return (<Picker.Item label={item} value={index} key={index}/>) 
    })}` , I am getting the error - `Invalid prop `label` of type `object` supplied to `PickerItem`, expected `string`.`

Comment: If I want to add an option e.g "Please Select" so what will I do for it?

Comment: @ZaInKhAn you can try adding a value at 0th index of options with  "Please Select"  as value

Answer (score 11):

corrected a couple of syntax errors

```
{options.map((item, index) => {
   return (< Picker.Item label={item} value={index} key={index} />);
})}
```