# React native picker Itemsource

Tags: reactjs, react-native, uipickerview

I'm using React native picker in react native.
Instead of supplying  Picker.Item for every Item. I want bind array as an Itemsource to Picker.

my array user-- ["100-1887-123","1231-123-123]

```
<Picker selectedValue = {this.state.user} onValueChange = {this.updateUser}>
           <Picker.Item label = "Steve" value = "steve" />
           <Picker.Item label = "Ellen" value = "ellen" />
           <Picker.Item label = "Maria" value = "maria" />
</Picker>
```

On selecting/value change I want get value of selected Item.
Please let me know how to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native apply array values from state as Picker items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43016624/react-native-apply-array-values-from-state-as-picker-items)

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just map over the array.

```js
var pickerItemArray = ["steve", "ellen", "maria"]

<Picker 
    selectedValue={this.state.user} 
    onValueChange={user => this.setState({ user })} // update your state here
>
   {pickerItemArray.map((item, index) => {
        return (<Picker.Item label={item} value={index} key={index} />) 
   })}
</Picker>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

define your `itemsource` in `constructor`

```js
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        itemsource: [
            { label: 'Steve', value: 'steve' },
            { label: 'Ellen', value: 'ellen' },
            { label: 'Maria', value: 'maria' }
        ],
        user: 'ellen'
    }
}
```

Loop over `itemsource` and `render` it

```js
renderPicker(){
    let itemsource = this.state.itemsource.map((item, i) =>  <Picker.Item key={i} label={item.label} value={item.value}/>);
    return(
        <Picker selectedValue = {this.state.user} onValueChange = {this.updateUser.bind(this)}>
            {itemsource}
        </Picker>
    );
}

render(){

    return(
        <View>
            {this.renderPicker()}
        </View>
    )
}
```

and update it

```js
updateUser(user){
    this.setState({user});
}
```