# Map object to generate Picker.Item instances in React Native triggers a "TypeError: undefined is not an object"

Tags: android, react-native, picker

My code is based off of this Stack Overflow question: [React Native apply array values from state as Picker items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43016624/react-native-apply-array-values-from-state-as-picker-items)

I used Manjeet Singh's first solution (for mapping an Object to Picker.Item instances) since I'm storing my data in an Object.

However, when I use his method, I'm getting a "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'child.props.value')" error.

My code looks like:

```
class View extends React.Component{
  state = { exercise: '' };
  arrItems = {"Badminton":"7", "Basketball":"9.3", "Biking":"8"};
  render(){
    <Picker selectedValue={this.state.exercise} 
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex)=>this.setState({ exercise: itemValue })>
       {Object.keys(this.arrItems).map((key) => {
        return (<Picker.Item label={key} value={key} key={key}/>)
      })}  
     }
    </Picker>
  }
```

I'm pretty new to React Native -- what is the issue causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

some small tips:

- Try to set your variables to the local state (this.state), at the
  moment I don't think you can reach your variables. You set state inside the construtor, the constructor (as shown below) and super() lines are necessary.
- You are missing a closing tag at the end of the onValueChange prop.
- `{ return(statement) }` equals `(statement)`, this only works if single
  line.
- You can use `.map((item, index) =>` to get the index of the item as well, so that you can use it as a key prop in the Item.

Try this:

```
class View extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      exercise: '',
      arrItems: { "Badminton": "7", "Basketball": "9.3", "Biking": "8" }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Picker selectedValue={this.state.exercise}
          onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ exercise: itemValue })}>
          {Object.keys(this.state.arrItems).map((key, index) =>
            <Picker.Item label={key} value={key} key={index} />
          )}
        </Picker>
    )
  }
}
```

Also you might want to rename your Class to something different than View, as you will probably use the built in View a lot (can only have one).