# Unable to map string array in state to Picker.item inside React Native Picker

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to populate a React Native picker with an array of strings I have stored in my state:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      designations: ["test", "test2"],
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
```

What I would like, is for my Picker element to populate the Picker.Items from the values inside this array in my state.

Here is my picker:

```
   <Picker
        selectedValue={this.state.designations[0]}
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ designation: itemValue })}
        
        {...Object.keys(this.state.designations).map((key) => {
                  return (<Picker.Item label={this.state.designations[key]} value={key} key={key}/>)
              })}
    />
```

I do not receive an error with this configuration, however the Picker has no items at all.

After reading [This thread about doing exactly what I'm trying to do,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43016624/react-native-apply-array-values-from-state-as-picker-items/43016866) I notice that they do not have a spread operator (...) infront of "Object" in theirs. However, when I try and do that in my code I recieve the following error:

```
'...' expected.
```

I have also tried the following (also from that thread):

```
         {...this.state.designations.map((item, index) => {
                 return (<Picker.Item label={item} value={index} key={index}/>) 
         })}
```

But unfortunately it is exactly the same as the above issue. I get an error if I do not use the spread operator, and when I do use the spread operator the picker list is not populated.

Any help or directions to look would be very welcome.

Comment: Look at the original thread.  The Picker.Item elements are children of the Picker element, so they go in between the <Picker> and </Picker> opening and closing tags.  Also, state.designations is an array so the second way of mapping you show is the correct one, without using Object.keys.

Comment: @BillDoughty you're correct! I feel really silly and I'm not sure how I missed that. I would mark your solution as the answer, but I am unable to since it's a comment. Cheers!